# How to check dictionary for duplicate keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Python dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, so something typed in like this:

```
chessSet = {'1b': 'wpawn', '1b': 'wking', '1c': 'wpawn'}
```

will be reduced to

```
chessSet = {'1b': 'wking', '1c': 'wpawn'}
```

How can I check and ensure the data entered into the dictionary does not have duplicate keys?

Overall, my goal would be an error message warning that this mistake was made.

Edit: more specifically, I am referring to trying to catch mistakes of typing this information into the source code. Is there a way to check if someone made a typo and created a second duplicate key which will overwrite the first one?

Comment: *When* do  you want this warning? To find it in literal source code like this, use a *linter*.

Comment: Your question as stated in the title is moot because dictionaries **cannot** contain duplicate keys. *Before* trying to add one, you could check if it is already present by using the conditional `key in mydict`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to if the key is already assigned and raise a warning.

```
chessSet = {'b1': 'wpawn', '1c':'wpawn'} 
def move(piece, to):
    if to in chessSet:
        initial_piece = chessSet[to]
        chessSet[to] = piece 
        print(f"{piece} has captured {initial_piece}")
    else:
        chessSet[to] = piece
```

Then you can try:

```
move('b1', 'wking')
```

And see what happens

Also:

```
move('b2', 'wking')
```